# How do i get my action listener to remove the contents from the current JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I am trying to add a button which will when pressed, clear the contents off the JPanel and return the panel back to its original set-up. How would i go about doing this? I have tried to revalidate, removeall etc but none have worked for me so far. Any suggestions on how i can do this? I will attach the code below, Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class WindowBlind extends JFrame
                         implements ChangeListener, ActionListener {

    private JSlider slider;           
    private int sliderValue = 0;  
    private JPanel panel;             
    private JButton open;
    private JButton close;
    private JButton exit;
    private boolean clear;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WindowBlind applic = new WindowBlind();
        applic.setLocation(100,100);
        applic.setVisible(true);

    } // main

    public WindowBlind() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setTitle("WindowBlind");
        setSize(300,300);

        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

        panel = new JPanel() {

                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g); 
                        paintScreen(g);         

                    } // paintComponent
                };
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,0,100,0);
        slider.setInverted(true);               // 0 will be at top, not bottom, of vertical slider
        window.add(slider);
        slider.addChangeListener(this);         // Register for slider events

        JButton open = new JButton("Open Slider");
        window.add(open);
        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              }
            });

        JButton close = new JButton("Close Slider");
        window.add(close);
        close.addActionListener(this);


        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit Slider");
        window.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);


    } // WindowBlind constructor

    public void paintScreen(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(70, 40, 60, 100);         // The blue sky
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.fillRect(70, 40, 60, sliderValue); // The blind, partially closed
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(70, 40, 60, 100);         // The window frame

    } // paintScreen

    // When the slider is adjusted, this method is called automatically
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

          sliderValue = slider.getValue();  // Fetch the slider's current setting
          repaint();                        // Force a screen refresh (paintComponent is called indirectly)

    } // stateChanged

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



    }


}
```

Comment: Define "original setup"

Comment: Have you tried changing `sliderValue` to `0` and then calling `repaint`?

Comment: Its original image....

Comment: So do you mean calling the method actionperformed and when the button is clicked change the slider value to 0?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much (and repaint the slider panel), since the fill amount is based on the `sliderValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a HUGE guess and assuming you want to reset the slider to it's "default" state, which would suggest that you need to change the `sliderValue`, something like...

```
close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sliderValue = 0;
        slider.repaint();
    }
});
```

A better solution would be to generate a self contained class which encapsulated all this functionality, for example...

```
public class SliderPane extends JPanel {

    private double sliderValue;

    public double getSliderValue() {
        return sliderValue;
    }

    public void setSliderValue(double sliderValue) {
        this.sliderValue = Math.max(Math.min(1.0, sliderValue), 0);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);          
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);         // The blue sky
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, (int)(sliderValue * height)); // The blind, partially closed
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);         // The window frame
    }

}
```

Then you could control the slider value through the `setSliderValue` method.

This also allows you to specify the slider value as percentage, meaning that the size of the component doesn't matter as the area filled is a percentage of the height

Comment: Oh what a surprise, yet another unsolicited downvote, seen as no new answers have been provided and no new downvotes or close votes have been made against the question and none of the other answers have been downvoted, I can only assume you have a personal dislike of me, unless you can provide some assistance as to why you might find my answers objectical, nothing is going to change

Answer (score 0):

This is because you always call `paintScreen` from the panel's `paintComponent` method. I would suggest this midification:

```
panel = new JPanel() {
                boolean drawMe = true;

                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g); 
                    if(drawMe)
                          paintScreen(g);         

                } // paintComponent
            };
```

Whenever you want to clear the panel, do this:

```
panel.drawMe=false;
panel.invalidate();
```

Comment: Could you place the clear panel inside of the action performed in the JButton exit??